# Simon's Algorithm using a Parity Check Matrix as Oracle

Tags: simons-algorithm

I've the following problem that I have to implement on IBM Q machine :

> In this exercise, you will implement Simon’s Algorithm to find a hidden subspace $H$ of
> codewords within the vector space $\mathbb{F}_2^n$ of binary strings of length $n$.
> The dimension of the hidden subspace is $k$ = 4. To implement the algorithm, you are
> given an oracle whose function is to apply the parity check matrix $P$ to any binary vector  of length $n$ = 7, where $P\underline{v} = 0$ if and only if $\underline{v} \in$ the hidden subspace $H$. In other words, consider two vectors $\underline{v_1}, \underline{v_2}$, $P(\underline{v_1} - \underline{v_2}) = 0$ iff $\underline{v_1} - \underline{v_2} ∈ H$. The parity check matrix $P$ is given by
> $$
> P = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\ 
> 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
> 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 
> \end{bmatrix}.
> $$

I do not understand how am I supposed to use $P$ to implement the fonction of the problem. Can someone help me ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: can someone help me ?